# Como ordenar entidades de Entity Framework Core a partir de un campo con la fecha en formato String y formato fecha española (dd/MM/yyyy)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-core

Tengo la siguiente entidad creada:

```
class ConferenciasImpartidasModel
    {
        public string ProgramacionLocalID { get; set; }
        public ProgramacionesLocalesModel ProgramacionLocal { get; set; }

        public int ConferenciaDisponibleID { get; set; }
        public ConferenciasDisponiblesModel ConferenciaDisponible { get; set; }
    }
```

El campo `ProgramacionLocalID` contiene una fecha en formato String, formato "dd/MM/yyyy" (25/04/2021). El problema es que quiero que con el método `OrderByDescending(c => c.ProgramacionLocalID)` al hacer una consulta sobre la entidad me las ordene de manera descendente por fecha. Pero al tener formato español para la fecha "dd/MM/yyyy", no me lo ordena correctamente. ¿Alguien sabría qué puedo hacer? Había pensado en añadir una propiedad `DateTime` que me ignorara al crear la tabla en el `Context` y que se almacenara con el valor de la fecha, pero parseado en formato `DateTime`. Sin embargo, intento hacerlo, pero no se cómo podría, pues me da errores constantemente.

¿Sabríais alguna otra solución? ¿O cómo elaborar esta misma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var ordenados = lista.ToList().OrderByDescending(l => DateTime.ParseExact(l.Fecha, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToList();
```

Aquí convertimos la fecha de **string** a un **objeto DateTime** mediante la **función ParseExact**.

Este método recibe tres parámetros:

**1**- La fecha como cadena de texto.

**2**- El formato en que está la fecha.

**3**- La cultura que no es más que un objeto que contiene el formato de las fechas, horas, números, monedas etcétera.

En nuestro ejemplo usamos **CultureInvariant** para no tener que especificar algún tipo de cultura. De esta forma vamos a obtener una lista ordenada descendentemente por la fecha.

Para utilizar al **objeto CultureInfo** debes poner en los **usings**:

```
using System.Globalization;
```

Comment: Mil gracias!!!!!!!!!!!! De verdad, me ha funcionado perfecto!! No sabes lo agradecido que te estoy!!! Muchísimas gracias, de verdad! ;)