# Consulta compleja Entity Framework Core en la que cojo las fechas máximas de los registros que están y no están en la tabla

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-core

Tengo dos tablas como las siguientes:

```
+--------------------------------------+    +--------------------------------------+
|               LECTORES               |    |         LECTORES PARTICIPAN          |
+----------+---------------------------+    +----------------+---------------------+
|    ID    |          NOMBRE           |    |    IDLector    |       FECHA         |
+----------+---------------------------+    +----------------+---------------------+
|     1    |          Perico           |    |       1        |      26/04/2021     |
+----------+---------------------------+    +----------------+---------------------+
|     2    |          Marian           |    |       1        |      30/04/2021     |
+----------+---------------------------+    +----------------+---------------------+
|     3    |          Luisa            |    |       5        |      29/04/2021     |
+----------+---------------------------+    +----------------+---------------------+
|     4    |          Pepa             |    |       4        |      31/04/2021     |
+----------+---------------------------+    +----------------+---------------------+
|     5    |          José             |    |       2        |      30/05/2021     |
+----------+---------------------------+    +----------------+---------------------+
|     6    |          Mariano          |    |       2        |      15/01/2021     |
+----------+---------------------------+    +----------------+---------------------+
|     7    |          Julián           |    |       3        |      18/02/2021     |
+----------+---------------------------+    +----------------+---------------------+
|     8    |          Samuel           |    |       1        |      20/03/2021     |
+----------+---------------------------+    +----------------+---------------------+
```

Un lector puede participar en lecturas más de una vez y en diferentes fechas, o puede que todavía no haya participado en ninguna. Tomando esto en cuenta, he definido ambas tablas con Entity Framework de la siguiente manera:

```
class Lectores
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public List<LectoresParticipanModel> LectoresParticipan;
}

class LectoresParticipan
{
    public int IDLector { get; set; }
    public string Fecha { get; set; } 
// Utilizo de tipo String para la fecha porque la base de datos es SQLite y no admite DateTime

    public Lectores Lector { get; set; }
}
```

La pregunta es: con estas entidades definidas y las tablas, me gustaría definir un método que obtuviese el lector que lleva más sin leer (o que todavía no ha leído). Se que necesitaría al menos hacer una consulta con Entity Framework Core en la que extrajese la fecha máxima de todos los lectores y lo ordenara de menor a mayor, y entonces eligiera el primero. Pero, ¿cómo podría hacer esto? ¿O habría otra manera mejor de hacerlo? Agradezco de antemano la respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para obtener los lectores que todavía no han leído harías esto

```
var sinLeer = from l in lectores
              where l.LectoresParticipacion.Count() == 0
              select l.nombre;
```

En esta consulta para cada lector preguntamos si su lista LectoresParticipacion no tiene elementos, para esto usamos el método Count, si es 0 quiere decir que este lector todavía no ha participado en ninguna lectura por tanto lo seleccionamos.

Ahora bien para obtener el lector que lleva más tiempo sin leer, la cosa es un poco mas dificil como bien tu dices en uno de tus comentarios, ya que el lector puede tener varias fechas, por tanto:

```
var ultimaFechaPorLector = (from l in lectores.ToList()
                            where l.LectoresParticipacion.Count() > 0
                            let listaP = l.LectoresParticipacion.ToList()
                            select new
                            {
                               Nombre = l.Nombre,
                               UltimaLectura = (from lp in listaP
                                                orderby DateTime.ParseExact(lp.Fecha, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                                                select new
                                                {
                                                   Fecha = DateTime.ParseExact(lp.Fecha, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                                                }).LastOrDefault();
                            }).ToList();
```

Primeramente hacemos una consulta que nos devolvera una lista de objetos anonimos con dos propiedades, **Nombre** de tipo **string**, la cual guardara el nombre de cada lector y **UltimaLectura** de tipo **DateTime**, la cual guardara la fecha mas reciente de lectura de ese lector, ya que la fecha mas reciente nos dira la ultima vez que ese lector hizo una lectura, y por tanto obviamos el resto de las fecha.

Como en tu modelo la fecha se guarda como **string** debemos transformarla a **DateTime**, para ello hacemos uso del metodo **ParseExact** de la clase **DateTime**, el cual recibe 3 parametros: la propiedad a transformar, el formato y la cultura. Puedes ver mas sobre ese metodo aqui: [Como ordenar entidades de Entity Framework Core a partir de un campo con la fecha en formato String y formato fecha española (dd/MM/yyyy)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/447018/como-ordenar-entidades-de-entity-framework-core-a-partir-de-un-campo-con-la-fech/447053#447053)

Para hacer uso del objeto **CultureInfo** debes poner en los usings:

```
using System.Globalization;
```

Con la lista que se obtiene de esta consulta es que vamos a obtener precisamente, el lector que lleva mas tiempo sin leer, aunque tambien pudieran ser los lectores que llevan mas tiempo sin leer, ya que puede haber mas de un lector con la misma fecha final de lectura, por tanto:

```
var sinLeer = (from u in ultimaFechaPorLector
               orderby u.UltimaLectura
               select u).ToList();

var fecha = sinLeer.FirstOrDefault().UltimaLectura;
```

Aqui lo que hacemos es guardar en la variable **sinLeer** todos los lectores ordenados ascendentemente por el campo **UltimaLectura**, al estar esta lista ordenada ascendetemente quiere decir que las primera posiciones de la lista son las mas antiguas y las ultimas posiciones de la lista son las mas recientes.

Como puede haber varios lectores que coincidan en la fecha de ultima lectura, guardamos en la variable **fecha**, la fecha del primer registro de la lista, es decir la fecha mas antigua y hacemos lo siguiente:

```
var resultadoFinal = sinLeer.TakeWhile(l => l.UltimaLectura == fecha).ToList();
```

Haciendo uso del metodo **TakeWhile**, tomaremos todos los elementos de la lista mientras estos tengan la propiedad **UltimaLectura** igual a la fecha que guardamos en la variable **fecha**, de esta forma obtendremos una lista con el o los lectores que llevan mas tiempo sin leer.

Comment: Creo que es casi lo que quería, pero, en la última consulta, al ordenar ascendentemente, si un lector ha leído la primera vez en la lista (tiene la fecha más antigua de lectura) y también es el último que ha leído (teniendo la fecha mayor de lectura), pues los registros se pueden repetir, ¿no daría un resultado incorrecto? ¿Igual habría que añadir para coger el máximo de la fecha?

Comment: Cierto, en un rato lo arreglo, te aviso

Comment: Gracias!!! Genial, sin problema jeje!!

Comment: @cjimenecue, ya revisa cualquier cosa me dices

Comment: Hola @Japv!! Perfecto, muchísimas gracias por el trabajo!! Lo único, una consulta: las fechas yo las tengo en formato "dd/MMM/yyyy", es decir, formato español. Entonces, al hacer `OrderBy(lp => lp.Fecha)`, el orden que dará no será el correcto, ¿puede ser? Perdóname, pues creo que no avisé de esto en el enunciado de la pregunta.

Comment: @cjimenecue, mañana vemos eso q donde vivo es tardisimo

Comment: Si, perfecto @Japv, sin ninguna prisa!! :) Ante todo, gracias. ;D

Comment: @cjimenecue, revisa y me dices

Comment: No se por qué me salta este error:

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123466/discussion-between-japv-and-cjimenecue).

Comment: @cjimenecue, arreglado, verifica y avisame

Comment: todo perfecto, muchísimas gracias!!